# Fictional vs. Fiction

Tags: nouns, adjectives

I apologize in advance if my question has been asked before: there's this club I know called the "Fiction Film Club", and while I know it's used here to specify what kind of film and that sometimes nouns are used as adjectives, but it still rubs me the wrong way. Shouldn't it be "Fictional Film Club"?

Thanks!

Comment: *Fictional films* could be interpreted as films that don't actually exist, and the *Fictional Film Club* could be a film club that doesn't actually exist, or a club devoted to films that don't actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

Study frequencies at Google Books (not vanilla Google):

["a Fiction Film and"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22put%20someone%20on%22%20idiom&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22a%20Fiction%20Film%20and%22)
About 4,180 results

"a Fictional Film and"
About 1,210 results

I'm using "and" to force phrase termination and to avoid its use as a noun pre-modifier.

I'd choose the first, as it also avoid the ambiguity pointed out by Peter Shor.